# copy row range vba and title row based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel, criteria

I have the below VBA coding that I am trying to modify.  I would like to only copy columns A:G  and the title and not the entire row.  Could you please help me modify? This code is copying the entire row based on the criteria in column D into a new worksheet titled as that criteria.

```
Sub Load_data()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String  
    Dim titlerow As Integer

    vcol = 4
    Set ws = Sheets("Transaction Details")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A7:G7"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(7).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next

        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""

        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If

        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("B7")
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `Dim vcol, i As Integer` only declares `i As Integer` but `vcol As Variant`. You need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim vcol As Integer, i As Integer`. • Also using `On Error Resume Next` without error handling is a bad idea. It just hides **all** error messages until `End Sub` in your code, but the errors still occur. You just cannot see them. So you cannot find and fix any errors below that line. Remove it or implement a complete error handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":G" & lr).Copy
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you!